# clamav: cannot scan from a file list on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8, clamav

`salt win8 grains.item osfullname`

```
win8:
    ----------
    osfullname:
        Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise Evaluation
```

`salt win8 cmd.run shell='powershell' '& "C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64\clamdscan.exe" -V'`

```
win8:
    ClamAV 0.98.7/21375/Tue Feb 16 05:36:54 2016
```

`clamd` is running on a Ubuntu VM. Here's the configuration on a Windows client (network mode):

```
TCPAddr <clamd.server.ip.address>
TCPSocket 3310
User Administrator
```

and I would like to scan only last 24 hours files by using something like this:

`salt win8 cmd.run shell='powershell' 'Get-ChildItem "C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | % { $_.FullName }'`

```
win8:
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\eicar.com.txt
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\file_to_scan.txt
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\report.txt
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\scan.ps1
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\sendmail.ps1
```

then write that list to a file:

```
| Out-File "C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\file_to_scan.txt"
```

and use `-f` option:

`salt win8 cmd.run shell='powershell' '& "C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64\clamdscan.exe" -h'`

```
win8:

                           ClamAV Daemon Client 0.99
               By The ClamAV Team: http://www.clamav.net/about.html#credits
               (C) 2007-2015 Cisco Systems, Inc.

        --file-list=FILE    -f FILE        Scan files from FILE
```

but I got this error when scanning:

`salt win8 cmd.run shell='powershell' '& "C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64\clamdscan.exe" -f "C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64\file_to_scan.txt"'`

```
win8:

    ----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
    Infected files: 0
    Total errors: 1
    Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
    ERROR: Can't access file C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\ÿþC
```

It always said that it cannot access a weird file named `ÿþC` in the current working directory:

`salt win8 cmd.run shell='powershell' 'cd \; & "C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64\clamdscan.exe" -f "C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64\file_to_scan.txt"'`

```
win8:

    ----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
    Infected files: 0
    Total errors: 1
    Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
    ERROR: Can't access file C:\\ÿþC
```

What is `ÿþC`? And why it said that?

PS: OS X client worked fine:

`clamdscan -f file_to_scan`

```
    /Users/quanta/Downloads/eicar.com.txt: Eicar-Test-Signature FOUND

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 1
Time: 4.359 sec (0 m 4 s)
```

---

**Tue Feb 16 22:54:26 ICT 2016**

Got another weird filename if running directly on the Windows VM:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> & 'C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\clamdscan.exe' -f 'C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\file_to_scan.txt'
ERROR: Can't access file C:\Windows\system32\ ■C

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is `ÿþC`?

`ÿþ` is a [representation of BOM (byte order mark) by UTF-16 (LE) encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding).

> And why it said that?

Because `Out-File` uses the encoding of the system's current ANSI code page by default:

> -Encoding
>
> Specifies the type of character encoding used in the file. Valid values are "Unicode", "UTF7", "UTF8", "UTF32", "ASCII", "BigEndianUnicode", "Default", and "OEM". "Unicode" is the default.
>   "Default" uses the encoding of the system's current ANSI code page.

The solution is use `-Encoding ASCII` to get rid of garbled characters:

`"C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) } | % { $_.FullName } | Out-File "C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\file_to_scan.txt" -Encoding ASCII'`

`Files\\ClamAV-x64'; & 'C:\\Program Files\\ClamAV-x64\clamdscan.exe' -f .\file_to_scan.txt"`

```
win8:
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\eicar.com.txt: Eicar-Test-Signature FOUND
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\file_to_scan.txt: OK
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\report.txt: OK
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\scan.ps1: OK
    C:\Program Files\ClamAV-x64\sendmail.ps1: OK

    ----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
    Infected files: 1
    Time: 5.845 sec (0 m 5 s)
    ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ab1beb83-9174-413c-b1a6-882cef213980/getting-garbled-text-with-outfile-?forum=winserverpowershell